# Bada 2.0 JSON parsing tutorial

Tags: json, bada, jsoncpp

**Anyone know good tutorial for bada 2.0 JSON Parsing.**

Went through the JSON parsing sample provided with bada SDK. I am relatively new to bada and c++ programming, so its difficult to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bada 2.0 added support for JSON parsing with namespace Osp::Web::Json

Check this out

http://developer.bada.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppapireference.help/classOsp_1_1Web_1_1Json_1_1JsonParser.html